# Bash `sleep` outputs __bp_preexec_invoke_exec

Tags: bash, command-line, for, sleep

### Background

I'm running a larger one-line command. It is unexpectedly outputting (twice per iteration) the following:

> __bp_preexec_invoke_exec "$_"

Here is the pared down command (removed other activity in loop):

```
for i in `seq 1 3`; do sleep .1 ; done
```

*note: after i have played with this a few times it inexplicably stops printing the unexpected output*

### What I've tried

- If I remove `sleep .5` I do not get the unexpected output
- If I simply run `sleep .5` the prompt returns but there is no output
- I have googled around for `__bp_preexec_invoke_exec`, but I am unable to determine how it applies to what I'm doing

### Question

What is *__bp_preexec_invoke_exec "$_"?*

How can I run this without the unwanted output?

---

### More info on solution thanks to @gina2x:

Here is the output of `declare -f | grep preexec`

```
    preexec_functions+=(preexec);
    __bp_preexec_interactive_mode="on"
__bp_preexec_invoke_exec ()
    if [[ -z "$__bp_preexec_interactive_mode" ]]; then
            __bp_preexec_interactive_mode="";
        __bp_preexec_interactive_mode="";
    local preexec_function;
    local preexec_ret_value=0;
    for preexec_function in "${preexec_functions[@]}";
        if type -t "$preexec_function" > /dev/null; then
            $preexec_function "$this_command";
            preexec_ret_value="$?";
    __bp_set_ret_value "$preexec_ret_value" "$__bp_last_argument_prev_command"
    if [[ -z "${iterm2_ran_preexec:-}" ]]; then
        __iterm2_preexec "";
    iterm2_ran_preexec="";
__iterm2_preexec ()
    iterm2_ran_preexec="yes";
```

I see in there a lot of "iterm2" information (I'm on a Mac and using iTerm2.app).

**In fact, when I try to reproduce using Terminal.app, I am *unable to reproduce* the unexpected output**.

Excellent sleuthing with `declare -f` - thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the bash debugger `-x` like: `bash -x -c 'for i in $(seq 3); do sleep .1 ; done'`

Comment: @hschou i will try it; i did just try it, but it's stopped the output again. it's very strange.

Comment: I bet you source some weird 3rd party script in `.bashrc`. Thus, first thing to try is run `bash --norc --noprofile` and repeat the exercise.

Comment: @jimmij well, ~/.bashrc only has this: `[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return` but i checked /etc/bashrc and while it also has a `are we an interactive shell?` section with a longer script, it seems to have come with centos (CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)). the unexpected output only seems to show once and then not for some unknown time after; possibly changing the length of the `sleep` argument starts the output again, but since it does it and then doesn't, it's hard to scientifically apply the debugging ideas given so far.  i'll keep trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like `__bp_preexec_invoke_exec` is part of https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec/blob/master/bash-preexec.sh. And it seems like that there is a bug in that script.

That project adds 'preexec' functionality to bash by adding DEBUG trap, I did not test, but I can imagine that it might not work properly in the way you see it. Check if it is installed in you environment - you could do so by `declare -f`. Seems like with newer bash you can use PS0 instead of that project, which probably would do the same without problems you see.

Comment: When I try to reproduce using Terminal.app instead of iTerm2.app (on mac), I am unable to reproduce the unexpected output.  Excellent sleuthing - I have added this and other supporting information to the bottom of my post for further clarification of what i was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Had the issue when migrating data from an old laptop to a new one. `__bp_preexec_invoke_exec` and some others are defined in and sourced from  `~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash` file.

In my case, the definitions were outdated, hence the noise.
Follow the instructions from the following link to download the latest version:
https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html